# Use Quick Responses with Hangouts' Implementation of Google Voice

Tags: sms, google-voice, google-hangouts, quick-responses

Back in the days of the original Google Voice app it was not possible to send quick replies when you're receiving a call through Google Voice.

But now that Google Voice is integrated with Hangouts is it possible? When I tried to set it up, it sent through the Hangouts app as expected but used my carrier number.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be supported yet, so only option at the moment may be to use Xposed framework to control that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "Quick Responses" in general but for all SMS and MMS messages sent via the Hangouts app, you can pick in the settings which number you would like to send it via. For example in my case I can choose to send from my Verizon number or my Google voice number.